# Dynamic List Application as first Vue.js App

Tags: javascript, to-do-list, vue.js

**Task Description:**

1. Create a div-element and take control over it using a Vue-Instance.
2. Print an array of hobbies into the div-element. Provide some default hobbies.
3. Add a 'New Hobby' button and a text-input element. So that the user can add additional hobbies.
4. When a hobby list-item is clicked, it shall be removed from the list.
5. Add a "Hobby deleted"-paragraph which is only shown when a hobby-item has been deleted at least one time.
6. Above the list of hobbies add a hobby-counter which shows the current count of hobby-items.
7. Style the hobby-list depending on whether you have more or less then 3 hobbies in the list.
8. Outsource  your hobbies (the list-item elements) into a component (so that it becomes re-usable).

**Here's my solution for the points 1 to 7:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    hobbies: [{
        name: 'Running'
      },
      {
        name: 'Chess'
      },
      {
        name: 'Cooking'
      },
      {
        name: 'Hiking'
      }
    ],
    newHobby: '',
    deleted: false
  },
  methods: {
    addHobby: function() {
      this.hobbies.push({
        name: this.newHobby
      });
    },
    removeHobby: function(event) {
      let updatedHobbies = this.hobbies.filter((hobby) => {
        return hobby.name !== event.target.textContent.trim();
      });

      this.hobbies = updatedHobbies;

      if (!this.deleted) {
        this.deleted = true;
      }
    },
    setStyle: function() {
      if (this.hobbies.length < 3) {
        return 'pink';
      } else if (this.hobbies.length === 3) {
        return 'orange';
      } else {
        return 'cyan';
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#app {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

li {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.3/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div id="hobby-counter">
    <p>Hobbies: {{ hobbies.length }}</p>
  </div>
  <div id="add-control">
    <input type="text" id="newHobby" v-model="newHobby" />
    <button v-on:click="addHobby" id="addNewHobby">Add New Hobby</button>
  </div>
  <div id="deleted-message">
    <p v-if="deleted">Hobby deleted!</p>
  </div>

  <li v-for="hobby in hobbies" v-on:click="removeHobby" v-bind:style="{ backgroundColor: setStyle() }">
    {{ hobby.name }}
  </li>
</div>
```

**Is everything done in a good way and manner?**

**Where could my implementation been improved?**

**Any ideas how to solve point 8?**

There I get finally stucked.

Looking forward to read your comments and answers.

Comment: `Any ideas how to solve point 8?` - that sounds like a request for advice about code not written. Please refer [to this post for more information regarding such requests](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3651/120114) - I would suggest you not ask that question, or this post may be closed as [_off-topic_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- At the moment all your current hobbies only consists of a name. I think you could use a simple string instead of wrapping it in an object (for point 8 this is not possible though, of course).
- No need to check `if (!this.deleted)` before setting `this.deleted = true;`
- `setStyle` should be a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html)
- You can use `@click` instead of `v-on:click`, you can also use `:style` instead of `v-bind:style` (just syntactic sugar)
- I would put the `v-if="deleted"` on the `<div id="deleted-message">` instead of the inner `<p>` element.

Answer (score 3):

Like I alluded to in [my comment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/181906/dynamic-list-application-as-first-vue-js-app#comment365147_181906), I considered voting to close your question because point #8 looked like a request for help implementing code that doesn't work. Alas, I will review the working code.

### Feedback

I agree with the points in [the answer by Simon](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/31562/simon-forsberg) - especially that there is no point to only setting `this.deleted` if it is *false*y. Below are some other aspects that I noticed.

#### Rendering a list without a key

See the section [key](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key) on the [List rendering page](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html) of the Vue JS documentation<sup>1</sup>:

> To give Vue a hint so that it can track each node’s identity, and thus reuse and reorder existing elements, you need to provide a unique `key` attribute for each item. An ideal value for key would be the unique id of each item.<sup>[2](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key)</sup>

Apparently the elements in your list don't have a unique `id`, but the array index can be used, using [the alternate `v-for` syntax](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#example-1):

```
<li v-for="(hobby, index) in hobbies"
```

That way the `index` (which is 0-based, since it is a JavaScript Array) will be available for the `key` attribute.

#### Removing items in constant time

That `index` mentioned in the previous section can be passed to the `removeHobby()` method, which could then use that index to call the JavaScript Array method [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) instead of `filter()`. As the list grows in size, the `filter()` approach would take more time, but calling `splice()` would be quicker because it would know the location of the element to remove. See this working in the snippet below.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    hobbies: [{
        name: 'Running'
      },
      {
        name: 'Chess'
      },
      {
        name: 'Cooking'
      },
      {
        name: 'Hiking'
      }
    ],
    newHobby: '',
    deleted: false
  },
  methods: {
    addHobby: function() {
      this.hobbies.push({
        name: this.newHobby
      });
    },
    removeHobby: function(index) {
      this.hobbies.splice(index, 1);
      this.deleted = true;
    },
    setStyle: function() {
      if (this.hobbies.length < 3) {
        return 'pink';
      } else if (this.hobbies.length === 3) {
        return 'orange';
      } else {
        return 'cyan';
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#app {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

li {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.3/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div id="hobby-counter">
    <p>Hobbies: {{ hobbies.length }}</p>
  </div>
  <div id="add-control">
    <input type="text" id="newHobby" v-model="newHobby" />
    <button v-on:click="addHobby" id="addNewHobby">Add New Hobby</button>
  </div>
  <div id="deleted-message">
    <p v-if="deleted">Hobby deleted!</p>
  </div>

  <li v-for="(hobby, index) in hobbies" v-on:click="removeHobby(index)" v-bind:style="{ backgroundColor: setStyle() }" :key="index">
    {{ hobby.name }}
  </li>
</div>
```

<sup>1</sup> <sub>and note that it actually contains a todo-list example, which you could have based your code off of...</sub>